# How to loop through an array of 100 objects with different properties and retrieve 1 property value from each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop, foreach

I have an array of 100 objects with different properties in each object. I am trying to do a for loop through the array to get 1 particular property from each object and push it to a new array. I've tried:

```
 for (var item in response.data) {
                main.allUsers.push(item);
            }
```

And when I console.log(main.allUsers); I get an array that looks like ["0","1", "2", "3", "4"...] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping through an object properties, the left-side of [the `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is a string that represents the current object's property name. So, you must use the notation object['property'] to get the correspondent value of that property. You should be using:

```
main.allUsers.push(response.data[item]);
```

---

Although, it seems your `response.data` is an Array, not an object, so, you shouldn't be using `for...in` at all, since it was designed to loop through object properties.

When looping through an Array, you should be using [the regular `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), or you can use the [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) loop, which will iterate similar to the way your trying with `for...in`. When ES6 be fully supported, you'll be able to use [the `for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), that's similar to what you're trying:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  var item = response.data[i];
  main.allUsers.push(item);
}
// or
response.data.forEach(function(item, i) {
  main.allUsers.push(item);
}
// and in the future (it already works in Firefox, if you wanna give a try)
for (var item of response.data) {
  main.allUsers.push(item);
}
```

---

**Update**

Answering to your comment, you could be using:

```
response.data.forEach(function(item) {
  main.allUsers.push(item.DisplayName);
});
// or
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  main.allUsers.push(response.data[i].DisplayName);
}
// or if you don't have any items inside main.allUsers yet
main.allUsers = response.data.map(function(item) { return item.DisplayName; });
```

Comment: Using the work `key` would make it more clear:
`for (var key in response.data)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Lets say I have [{DisplayName: "Mike", UserName: "CoolGuy"},{DisplayName: "Steve", UserName: "Stevey"}.....] I want to take all the DisplayName properties from this array and push them to the main.allUsers array. I tried your example and it gave me undefined for each object.

Comment: couldn't the very last "answer" be simply `main.allUsers = response.data.map(function(item) { return item.DisplayName; });`

Comment: @JaromandaX it depends if the `main.allUsers` already have items. But I could be using `concat`.

Comment: in that case, the `forEach` is the best solution ... never any need to do a map and a forEach

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, agreed with you. I've only showed more than one possibility, because depending on the complexity of his real code, it could be good for him learn new stuff.

Comment: My heart goes out to you. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me and for the detailed response. It worked and I greatly appreciate it!!! And thank you to everybody for taking the time to respond to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you could also do the following.. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay6csj4s/)

```
    var arrayOfObjects = [
        {name: "myName1",
         age: 12
        },
        {surname: "mySurname2",
         age: 26
        }
        //98 more...
    ];

    var myData = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++){ //iterate array of objects
        for(var key in arrayOfObjects[i]){ //iterate each object key
            if(arrayOfObjects[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && key == "age"){ 
                //make sure its the key you want
                myData.push(arrayOfObjects[i].age);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get each object in an array, you have to use

```
for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
    var obj = response.data[i];
}
```

And now to get each property of object,

```
for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
    var obj = response.data[i];
    for (property in obj){
       console.log(property);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. We are getting close. I got all the properties but how do I get the value from a particular property from that list.

Comment: in inner for loop You can write a condition like if(property === 'youwant'){newArray.push(property)}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `for..in` with arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in. Use `forEach`, or standard `for`, or `map`. Like:

```
var _len = response.data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
  main.allUsers.push(response.data[i]);
}
```